# How to convert from row to column?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a .txt file with numbers ordered like this (on the same row):

```
106849_01373    106849_01967    106850_00082    23025.7_01059
```

I would like to convert them like that:

```
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
```

I have no idea which command to use. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one with [`xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xargs.1posix.html)

```
xargs -n1 < file.txt
```

Demo:

```
$ cat file.txt                    
106849_01373    106849_01967    106850_00082    23025.7_01059 

$ xargs -n1 < file.txt
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
```

Comment: xargs is a great tool, and If you hadn't mentioned it, I would have, but it does have one drawback in that if you omit the command it substitutes echo (which unlike in some shells, xargs does not have a builtin echo) and -n1 tells xargs to call the command for every arg, so with this example you would have a minimum of six processes involved (the shell to do the io redirection, xargs, and four echos). This is not so bad at this scope, but it is measurably slower at a couple thousand lines output.

Answer (score 16):

Pretty easy with `tr`:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' <file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                    
106849_01373    106849_01967    106850_00082    23025.7_01059   
106849_01373    106849_01967    106850_00082    23025.7_01059   
106849_01373    106849_01967    106850_00082    23025.7_01059   
106849_01373    106849_01967    106850_00082    23025.7_01059   

% tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' <file.txt
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
```

Answer (score 2):

heemayl's answer is the way to go, however here's an alternative using Perl:

```bsh
perl -lane '$,="\n"; print(@F)' file.txt
```

- `-l`: enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate effects. First, it automatically chomps $/ (the input record separator) when used with -n or -p. Second, it assigns $\ (the output record separator) to have the value of octnum so that any print statements will have that separator added back on. If octnum is omitted, sets $\ to the current value of $/.
- `-a`: turns on autosplit mode when used with a -n or -p. An implicit split command to the @F array is done as the first thing inside the implicit while loop produced by the -n or -p.
- `-n`: causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk:

  ```perl
  LINE:
    while (<>) {
        ...             # your program goes here
    }
  ```
- `-e`: may be used to enter one line of program;
- `$,="\n"`: sets the output field separator to a newline;
- `print(@F)`: prints the fields separated by the output field separator.

```
% cat file.txt
106849_01373    106849_01967    106850_00082    23025.7_01059 
% perl -lane '$,="\n"; print(@F)' file.txt
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/\s\{1,\}$//' -e 's/\s\+/\n/g' file.txt > split_file.txt
```

Comment: Not quite..it would add a trailing newline after each (initial) line..

Comment: Check with multiple lines, you would get a clear case then..

Comment: Could you add an example with your answer..

Comment: @heemayl You meant it would turn trailing spaces into newlines. Your syntax doesn't make it easy to understand. :/

Answer (score 1):

`AWK` approach. Basically changing the output separator for fields, and looping. The test file is your example pasted over and over with ENDLINE at the end

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' some_data 
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
ENDLINE
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
ENDLINE
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
ENDLINE
```

Answer (score 1):

I just add a Python solution for fun:

```
python3 -c 'import sys; f=open(sys.argv[1]); print(*f.read().split(),sep="\n")' mytestfile
```

This command runs the one-line Python 3 script in 'single quotes' with the file name you want to convert as argument in the end. The syntax is like this:

```
python3 -c 'PYTHON_COMMAND_OR_1-LINE-SCRIPT' ARGUMENTS
```

The 1-line-script we use is this (expanded to multiple lines for clarity):

```py
import sys
f=open(sys.argv[1])
print(*f.read().split(),sep="\n")
```

It imports the `sys` module to read command-line arguments, takes the first given argument as file name to open and prints each whitespace separated data chunk from the file in a single line.

```
$ cat mytestfile 
106849_01373    106849_01967    106850_00082    23025.7_01059   
106849_01373    106849_01967    106850_00082    23025.7_01059   
106849_01373    106849_01967    106850_00082    23025.7_01059   
106849_01373    106849_01967    106850_00082    23025.7_01059   

$ python3 -c 'import sys; f=open(sys.argv[1]); print(*f.read().split(),sep="\n")' mytestfile
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
106849_01373
106849_01967
106850_00082
23025.7_01059
```